# form input and submit button in same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create search field, now this is how it looks on all browsers except chrome

[image]

This is how it looks in chrome:

[image]

And here is my css:

```
#search_input{
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-image: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
border-color: #DEDEDE;
border-style: solid none solid solid;
border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px;
height:25px;
padding-left:3px;
}


#search_submit {
position: relative;
right: 4px;
top: 8px;
}
```

Also html:

```
<form action="#">
    <input id="search_input" type="text" name="search" />
    <input id="search_submit" type="image" src="../media/images/search_button.jpg" />
</form>
```

Sorry for such a long post i just wanted to make thing clear, anyways how do i fix this problem with chrome?

**EDIT** Here is the button http://shinigami.cd.lt/media/images/search_button.jpg

input is done by css no image used.

Comment: Can you publish the image? `search_button.jpg`, for testing purposes? This is the basic fiddle to start off: http://jsfiddle.net/BJJ38/

Comment: could you put those images button somewhere on net (or better provide whole example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [cssdesk](http://cssdesk.com/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your image is wrong.

The height of your image has to be:

```
<height of input> + <padding of input> + <border of input>
= 25 + 0 + 2x1 = 27px
```

The corrected CSS can be found here (applied zoom for debugging purposes):
http://jsfiddle.net/BJJ38/2/

To make sure that the input elements look as expected, you have to explicitly define the `padding-top` and `-bottom` properties. Merged with your `padding-left`, the following property shows up:

```
padding: 0 0 0 3px;
```

Also, you have to define a width for a consistent look. For example:

```
width: 50px;
```

An alternative approach would be placing the button inside the input field, and extending the right padding, so that the outline on focus looks better: http://jsfiddle.net/BJJ38/3/

Comment: I don't have time to test your solution right now, but i hope it's going to work, thanks

Comment: You can have a quick look at the JSFiddles.